# How can I solve my .length undefined issue?

Tags: javascript

I get a .length error on line 2 here.

> index.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Code:

```
<div class="formCustomerName">
         <label>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="customerName" placeholder="Name" value="" 
required>
</div>



let name = document.getElementById('customerName').value;

form.addEventListener('input', pushData, false);{
    if (name.value.length >= 0) {
        btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        document.getElementById('submitInput').innerHTML = ("Hello If statment here!")

    } else {
        document.getElementById('submitInput').innerHTML = ("Hello Else statment here!")
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }



function pushData() {
```

Comment: Sounds like whatever `name` is, it doesn't have a `value` property. Pretty sure you've made some typos at the top of this snippet too.

Comment: Simply put,name.value is undefined... Initialize it with a value

Comment: You are calling value twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored the `value` of customerName to `name`.

Then, you try to access `name.value.length`, which is essentially

```
document.getElementById('customerName').value.value.length
```

As the `value` property doesn't have another `value` property, it returns `undefined` and hence the error.

To solve it, remove `.value` from the definition of `name`:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('submitButton');
let form = document.getElementById('form');
let name = document.getElementById('customerName');

form.addEventListener('input', pushData, false); 

function pushData(){
  if (name.value.length >= 0) {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
    document.getElementById('submitInput').innerHTML = ("Hello If statment here!")

  } else {
    document.getElementById('submitInput').innerHTML = ("Hello Else statment here!")
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="formCustomerName">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="customerName" placeholder="Name" value="" required>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <div id="submitInput"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
let name = document.getElementById('customerName').value;
```

So name is **value** of element with ID `customerName`.

```
name.value.length >= 0
```

means `element.value.value.length`. You should have this in condition:

```
name.length >= 0
```

Comment: This way round it returns IF statement on page refresh, Withoout entering any values into the field.